# P2P "Serverless" com Godot Engine, através de Requests

Tags: redes

Estou desenvolvendo um jogo baseado em Turnos 1v1 na [Godot Engine](https://godotengine.org), e estou tendo dificuldade para conectar dois jogadores como em um matchmaking. Meu problema é que não quero um servidor central propriamente dito, se for possível, gostaria que um servidor de web hosting fosse suficiente.

A ideia que tive é de utilizar Requests HTTP para obter o IP do adversário, e isso já consegui fazer, mas não consigo, utilizando o RPC do Godot, iniciar uma conexão não-local.

Não precisa ser da forma que eu descrevi, nem da forma como estou pensando, basicamente quero que o jogo conecte dois jogadores sem a necessidade de um servidor central que administre o jogo, apenas que a obtenção do IP do adversário seja por requests HTTP.

Entendo pouco de redes para obter uma solução para isso, mas acredito que o problema está relacionado com NAT ou Firewall, existe alguma forma de implementar uma conexão P2P possuindo apenas o IP Externo do adversário?

Outra ideia que tive, um pouco mais complicada, seria de implementar algo como um Tunneling similar ao Hamachi, mas que fizesse isso automaticamente ao invés de manualmente, conectar dois jogadores à mesma "sala", pois já testei e através do Hamachi a conexão funciona, o que eu precisaria saber para implementar isso, se for a opção mais fácil para atingir o objetivo?

**TLDR**:
Preciso estabelecer conexão entre apenas dois jogadores na [Godot Engine](https://godotengine.org), basicamente a conexão inicial porque após, o RPC do Godot já faz todo o resto.
A questão é que não quero um servidor central, gostaria de, se necessário, apenas um servidor de web hosting que consiga fazer isso usando apenas Requests HTTP, pelo menos para fazer o Godot estabelecer a conexão inicial, ou seja, intermediar a conexão entre dois jogadores.